# Geometry returned from hitTest() throws "Invalid query parameters" when used as query geometry

Tags: arcgis-js-api

## Intended effect

When user clicks on view, hitTest() returns geometry from visible polygons that are to be used in a query by location on `localitiesLayer` (point features). Code snippet and photo below to demonstrate desired behavior.

```
    view.on("click", function(event) {
      selectFeaturesFromClick(event);
    });

    function selectFeaturesFromClick(clickEvent) {
      var includeLayers = [countiesLayer, neighborhoodsLayer, regionsLayer, clientFeatureLayer]
      view.hitTest(clickEvent, {include: includeLayers}).then(function(response) {
        if (response.results.length > 0) {
          selectFeatures(clickFeature);
        }
     });
    }
    
    function selectFeatures(feature) {
      var geometry = feature.geometry;
      var query = {
        geometry: geometry,
        spatialRelationship: "intersects",
        outFields: ["*"], 
        returnGeometry: true
      }
      localitiesLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results) {
        ...
      });
     }
```

[Image of app with desired behavior (Riverside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIQrN.png)

## Issue

When certain features from the hosted feature layer `countiesLayer` are clicked, the query request cannot be completed with the following error message: "Cannot perform query. Invalid query parameters".

For whatever reason, this seems to occur with most of the features but not with all of them. As shown with the photo above, it works as intended when "Riverside" is clicked but not "Los Angeles" as shown in the image below.

[Image of app displaying bug (Los Angeles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj80G.png)

## Troubleshooting

At first I thought it might have something to do with the localityLayer being not loaded at the time of the `.query()`, but that wouldn't account for the other feature layers working just fine.

I can't seem to figure out what would be different in the features that do seem to work and those that don't. The other feature layers included in the hit test seem to work as expected.

**Updates**

- When a `LayerView` of the `localitiesLayer` is used for the query, the app works as intended. However I would rather not have to continuously update the a LayerView as it seems to impact performance when users are constantly panning/zooming around the map. And furthermore, I have had issues querying all fields from a LayerView.
- Per user Arno Fiva's suggestion on using the `createQuery()` method, it is now reflected in the CodePen linked below. The issue persists with the proposed solution.

## Question

Is this specifically related to the way that I have written the `hitTest()`?
I've included a link to a CodePen with the app for anyone who would like to take a look.

[CodePen of app with bug](https://codepen.io/dmarkbreiter/pen/BaLLOmq)

Comment: It seems to me that is has some problem when intersect with multi polygons .. If you try the query with the "biggest" ring of Los Angeles (continental polygon ring) it will intersect 2196 features (tested with count only), and will retrieve the max features, 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a [`Query`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html) object from scratch, have the layer create a query first and then extend it with additional parameters:

```js
var query = localitiesLayer.createQuery();
query.geometry = geometry;
query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";
query.outFields = ["*"];
query.returnGeometry = true;

localitiesLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results) {
  ...
});
```

When the layer creates the query, it will pre-fill all necessary parameters to avoid the error message you describe above. See [`FeatureLayer.createQuery()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#createQuery) for more info. As for why it sometimes works and sometimes not, that would have to be investigated, possible even on the REST API side.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However, when using the createQuery method on the `localitiesLayer`, the problem does not appear to be fixed. I updated the CodePen (link in the post) with the solution you described in your post.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from GeoNet (link below) simplifies the geometry before the query.

[GeoNet Solution](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript/geometry-returned-from-hittest-throws-quot-invalid-query/m-p/1009052#M71095) (from [JohnGrayson)](https://community.esri.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/11373)

```
// simplification distance can be static based on your data
// or dynamic based on current view scale or other relevant context

var geometry = geometryEngine.simplify(polygon.geometry, 1000);
```

While this solves the problems asked in this question, it does not appear to fix the other issue brought up by user [@cabeson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2701198/cabesuon), of feature counts over 2000 not being properly calculated.